# Parsing an XML tree with RapidXML and discarding unwanted nodes

Tags: c++, xml, rapidxml, phylogeny

I am interested in using RapidXML to parse an XML tree; however, this XML has several layer of rows that I do not need. This is because it is a representation of a genetic tree and many layers are called "clade" which is essentially useless info to me.

For example, here is a sample of the document:

```
<phylogeny rooted="true" rerootable="false">
  <clade>
    <clade>
      <taxonomy>
        <scientific_name>Neomura</scientific_name>
      </taxonomy>
      <clade>
        <taxonomy>
          <id provider="uniprot">2759</id>
          <scientific_name>Eukaryota</scientific_name>
          <rank>superkingdom</rank>
        </taxonomy>
        ............
      </clade>
    </clade>
  </clade>
</phylogeny>
```

This part of the tree should represent that *Eukaryota* is a child of *Neomura* which is in turn a child of *phylogeny*. However, if I parsed it using RapidXML without consideration of the appearance of the *clade* nodes, then it would have several unnecessary layers. Does anyone have any ideas how to proceed with this?

Comment: I'm not really sure where to begin. I know how to use a for loop to cycle through the nodes and add each one to a tree, but I'm not sure how I should skip a node and resume adding nodes to the tree.

Comment: How about an `if` statement in your loop?